# Lost colors and legend after ggplot upgrade

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, legend

I really like the way ggplot2 2.0 improved the looks, but suspect that the upgrade changed the way colors and legend is defined. How can I update my code for ggplot 2.0?

The first abline should be black (and still is). Should not be in legend.

The ablines "Line1", "Line2", and "Line3" should have different colors, and be in legend. They are all black now.

The legend should be visible, but is not anymore.

```
library(ggplot2)
plot.data <- data.frame(x=c(2, 8), y=c(3, 6))
p <- ggplot(plot.data, aes(x=x, y=y))
p <- p + geom_point(color="black")
p <- p + geom_abline(intercept=0, slope=0.5, color="black", linetype="dashed")
#p <- p + geom_abline(intercept=0, slope=1, aes(color="Line1"), linetype="dashed", show_guide=TRUE)
p <- p + geom_abline(intercept=0, slope=1, aes(color="Line1"), linetype="dashed", show.legend=TRUE)
p <- p + geom_abline(intercept=0, slope=2, aes(color="Line2"), linetype="dashed")
p <- p + geom_abline(intercept=0, slope=3, aes(color="Line3"), linetype="dashed")
p <- p + xlim(0,10)
p <- p + ylim(0,10)
p <- p + theme(legend.title=element_blank(), legend.position="bottom")
p
```

With the original code (with # in example above) I get a warning message "`show_guide` has been deprecated. Please use `show.legend` instead`", but changing show_guide to show.legend above makes no difference.

Note: I'm not 100% sure it is the upgrade that is the problem, it might be my original example that is wrong.

Comment: I just playdr with your code and if you move aes() the legend will appear. try: p + geom_abline(aes(intercept=0, slope=1, color="Line1"), linetype="dashed", show.legend=TRUE)

Comment: Great! That solved it. Do you want to make it an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just repost my comment here as an answer.

to make the legend reappear, the intercept and the slope also have to be in the aes() call.

```
p + geom_abline(aes(intercept=0, slope=1, color="Line1"), linetype="dashed", show.legend=TRUE)
```